# Is there a way to copy a selected area up or down in vim?

Tags: vim, remap, pasting

In VSCode you can copy and paste selected lines of text up or down using Alt+Shift + Up or Down.

I switched to vim a few months ago, and I really miss this feature.
I found out you can move selected lines in visual mode up or down using these visual mode bindings,

```
vnoremap J :m '>+1<CR>gv=gv
vnoremap K :m '<-2<CR>gv=gv
```

but it'd be great if you could copy and paste up and down as well without using yy and p because when you're done yanking, the cursor is placed at the initial position, exiting visual mode and reducing productivity.

Comment: I see no question, only a suggestion.

Answer (score 5):

Well, that, here, is the problem with copying and pasting random snippets from the internet without understanding what they do: they are little black boxes that one can't modify or extend at will by lack of knowledge.

Let's deconstruct the first mapping:

```
vnoremap J :m '>+1<CR>gv=gv
```

- `:[range]m {address}` *moves* the lines covered by `[range]` to below line `{address}`. Here, the range is automatically injected by Vim: `'<,'>` which means "from the first line of the latest visual selection to its last line", and the address is `'>+1`, meaning "the last line of the latest visual selection + 1 line". So `:'<,'>m '>+1<CR>` effectively *moves* the selected lines below themselves,
- `gv` reselects the latest visual selection,
- `=` indents it,
- `gv` reselects it again for further `J`s or `K`s.

Now, we want a similar mapping but for *copying* the given lines. Maybe we can start with `:help :m` and scroll around?

Sure enough we find `:help :copy` right above `:help :move`, which we can try right away:

```
xnoremap <key> :co '>+1<CR>gv=gv
```

Hmm, it doesn't really work the way we want but that was rather predictable:

- the address is one line below the last line of the selection,
- the selection is reselected and indented, which is pointless.

We can fix the first issue by removing the `+1`:

```
xnoremap <key> :co '><CR>gv=gv
```

and fix the second one by selecting the copied lines instead of reselecting the latest selection:

```
xnoremap <key> :co '><CR>V'[=gv
```

See `:help :copy` and `:help '[`.